# Why only get 1 tweet when using tweepy?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitter-search

A few days ago, I applied a twitter developer account to be used with tweepy library. I tried to scrape with keyword like Google, get a lot of tweets. But after I tried to scrape data with specific keyword, I only got 1 tweet, even though tweets related to those keyword were pretty much on Twitter.

```
tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
                   q='simas jiwa',
                   lang="id",
                   since=datetime.date(2005, 10, 6)).items(100)
```

The result is like this:

```
@SimasJiwa asuransi simas jiwa aman2 saja kan ?
```

How to solve this problem? Why only get 1 tweet?

Comment: The standard search API only goes back up to 7 days, so you will not be able to search from the date you've provided. I think there are only a few results in the past 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

There’s a option you can add to the Cursor. Max amount without a license is 100 though

```
Count=x
```

Comment: I have already added count to the cursor, but the result still same, i only get 1 tweet @Sam Dean